# how to check if openvpn is active

Tags: php, openvpn, curl

i am runnning multiple openvpn instances each connected to different servers
let's assume there are 3 
and i am using a simple php script with this command

```
system('openvpn config1');
system('openvpn config2');
system('openvpn config3');
```

the config file conatin daemon and route-nopull ,at the end i'll tun0 tun1 tun2 enabled
when i want to use tun0 i use

```
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "tun0");
```

now the first problem is if there was some problem with the interface,curl timeout won't work ! it will hang for there forever until i abort it mannually

and the second problem is even openvpn won't kill the interface if the connection failed for some reason,how  can i check if the connection is alive all the time (keepalive 10 60 didn't do the trick,i don't know why)

i am not an expert in openvpn,and they don't have a lot of informations in their manual 
so how can i make sure all the time that the connection on a specific interface is working,and if it is not i wan't to kill that openvpn instance,and what is the solution for the curl timeout when using CURLOPT_INTERFACE

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is checking the link status. For example:

```
$ ip link show tun0
11: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 500
link/none
```

In the event it is active, you will see `UP` in those <>. You can also check that there are active routes associated with the interface. No active routes would mean the interface would go unused.

```
$ ip ro show dev tun0
default via x.x.x.x dev tun0  scope link  metric 1
```

The most correct way is to enable the management interface on the openvpn daemon and ask it the link status directly and read any errors. The [documentation for the management interface is out on the openvpn site](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html).

As far as the curl timeout, I don't know why it would do that. You may want to open a defect for it with PHP if it is reproducible with the most recent version.

Answer (score -1):

```
ping -c  1 whoami.ultradns.net
```

Returns your IP address (of your client).
So very easy to see if your VPN is active / what VPN server you are connected via e.g in a Foreign country.

No config required.

Comment: This identifies a DNS server, not a VPN server.